# Clean UI elements watchOS 2 after lock

Tags: user-interface, refresh, watchkit, watch

When the app starts is Apple watchOS2 it calls:

```
awakeWithContext
```

Then, if you lock and unlock the app, the lifecycle calls:

```
willActivate
```

The problem that I have is that I cannot remove the UI elements (clean screen), without user see the "old" screen during 1 second.

From the Apple documentation:

**didDeactivate:**

*-Do not use this method to modify your interface......Modifications can be made only during initialization of your interface controller and between calls to willActivate and this method.*

but then in **willActivate** method:

*.... Do not use this method to perform the initial setup of your interface.*

I don't know what I have to do to "clean" the screen when the user locks the app.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Apple:

*Thank you for contacting Apple Developer Technical Support (DTS). Our engineers have reviewed your request and have concluded that there is no supported way to achieve the desired functionality given the currently shipping system configurations.*